# Is this a simple and sound proof of Bertrand's Postulate in the form $2p_{n}>p_{n+1}$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I was playing with sequences and I thought of a really simple proof of this  theorem. Bertrand's postulate has been proved by Chebyshev but I thought this was interesting.

Theorem: $2p_{n}>p_{n+1}$ where $p_{n}$ is the prime number sequence.

Proof:

Given the difference between consecutive primes $p_{n+1}-p_n=g_n,$ define a sequence $a_n$ to be the number that when added to $g_n$ gives $p_n.$ So we have,

$p_{n+1}-p_n+a_n=p_n.$

Solving for $a_n$ we have,

$a_n=2p_n-p_{n+1}.$

For $n>1$ the primes differ at the very least by $2$, so $a_n$ must be greater than $0$ and therefore $2p_n>p_{n+1}.$
$\square$

Am I missing something or is this proof sound?

Comment: primes differing by 2 means $g_n>0$, not $a_n>0$. A counterexample to Bertrand is exactly when $a_n<0$.

Comment: I see, but $a_n$ cannot be less than 0 because it is what must be added to $g_n$ to get $p_n$ and this is clearly greater than 0. Because $p_n$ is clearly greater than $g_n$ no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first glance, your proof is *probably* wrong simply because it is too simple. It really does look like you are missing something. Sure, there exists simple proofs, but it should immediatelly raise an alarm as they aren't that common, especially as-yet-undiscovered very simple proofs of complex theorems.

---

A deeper inspection reveals your mistake:

You haven't shown why $a_n>0$, which is exactly what you need to show. There are two ways of looking at what you did and how it is wrong:

1. You define $a_n$ as "what needs to be added to $g_n$ to get $p_n$. In this step, you *assumed* that $g_n$ is indeed **smaller** than $p_n$, but you don't know that yet. For all you know, $g_n$ could be greater than $p_n$, so then $a_n$ would be smaller.
2. Equivalently, you defined $a_n$ as the solution to the equation $g_n+a_n=p_n$, meaning you **defined** $a_n$ to be $2p_n-p_{n+1}$. From this definition you can see that proving $a_n>0$ is equivalent to proving the entire theorem, so you haven't moved anywhere yet.

Comment: I see. But, $p_n$ is always greater than $g_n$ for $n>2$ no? The sequence $a_n$ must be greater than $0$ as a result. Am I wrong in this?

Comment: @e2theipi2026 $p_n$ is greater than $g_n$ **if and only if** $a_n$ is greater than $2p_n>p_{n+1}$, which is what you still have to show.

Comment: @e2theipi2026 Here's a general hint: if you think something is true, and even obviously true, then prove it. Try to draw a sketch of the proof. If you cannot, then the thing is (obviously) not obvioulsy true.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @e2theipi2026 Another way of looking at it: $g_n$ is the difference between two primes. Saying that $g_n$ is smaller than $p_n$ is **precisely** the same thing as saying "the difference between $p_n$ and $p_{n+1}$ is smaller than $p_n$", which is precisely the same thing as saying "$p_{n+1}$ is somewhere between $p_n$ and $p_{n+1}$, which is the postulate you want to prove.

Comment: Yah I get it. I'm beginning with the assumption that $p_n>g_n$ and I haven't proved that. O well, knew it was too good to be true.